# Servlet redirect doesn't display requested page

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

I have a page - lets call it page X - where I do an `ajax` call that populates my table constructed with `jqGrid`. So here I call `localhost:8080/servlet/ajax/Data.json` which is a `servlet`.
Now, if the page expires and the user still wants to access the table (search data for instance) I would like to redirect the request to the `Login` page.

The `ajax` call calls the Data.json `servlet` that is not in the same `servletcontext` as my `Login` page (which is `localhost:8080/servlet/myapp`), therefore I cannot use `servlet` forward (I am using JBoss 4.2 and I can only forward in the same `servletcontext`).

I have tried to redirect with `sendRedirect`, which is able to call the `Login` page that is actually executed but not displayed. And this is where I got lost. My `Login` page is executed and I still see page X. 
I have tried to write the returned HTML (from `Login` page) into the response of page X (I also set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`). The HTML is returned in the response, but not displayed.

I am using `Apache Turbine` which is another `servlet` that retrieves a page when requested.
Do you have any ideas? I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous calls, sendRedirect call on ajax calls never be effective (ajax response always sends response to initiator).

You may need to use XMLHttpRequest status code to find out the page expiration and then use java script window.location to reset the browser url to login url.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your servlet at `servlet/ajax/Data.json` is telling the AJAX request to redirect to the login page. Then the page is going to try to render the jqGrid table with the login page, which probably won't work.

You need to add code where you are making the AJAX call to `servlet/ajax/Data.json` to check to see whether the browser itself needs to be redirected. Either if the servlet returns a 302 redirect as a response, or if the servlet returns an error that's simply "SESSION EXPIRED", so the javascript on the browser's end that's making the AJAX call to the servlet knows the session has expired and to redirect the browser to the login page.